# What items are needed to build a caddy?

Tags: die2nite

Does anybody know what items are needed?  I can't find the info anywhere yet...

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean "A Broken Caddy Cart"

- Duct Tape
- Wrought Iron
- Copper Pipe

[Source](http://die2nite.wikia.com/wiki/Items#Miscellaneous)

> "A broken caddy cart." It can be fixed with Duct Tape, Wrought Iron and Copper Pipe. Wonky Caddy Cart gives you 2 additional slots within your original rucksack for more item storage while you wear it. Because it is a heavy object you can't take any other heavy objects. (Cannot be used in addition to a Manbag)

Comment: Excellent, so does this mean you need to have the broken caddy cart and use those objects to make it a wonky caddy cart?

Comment: @Mike Many items need to be "built" to be used.  The Caddy is one of them.  By putting the appropriate items in your inventory (plus the broken Caddy) you can then "build" the Caddy to produce a working one.